# Passing post variables from java android app to php file to query database

Tags: php, android, sql, android-async-http

I'm creating an android app that has a login screen. The user must enter their email address and password. When hitting the login button, my code is supposed to send the typed username and password into a php file using post variables. The php file is supposed to use the variables sent from the app to complete the select statement, and return the results from the database on the server if there are any matches.
When running the app, the output returned from the php file is blank. 
I don't know if the post variables are being sent to the php file correctly, I've searched all over the internet but can't seem to understand how this concept works.

Below is my code:

```
package com.example.csqa;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AsyncHttpPost extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    TextView t;
    MainActivity ma;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

public AsyncHttpPost(MainActivity m, List<NameValuePair> nvp){
    ma = m;
    nameValuePair = nvp;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    byte[] result = null;
    String str = "";
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);// in this case, params[0] is URL

    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            result = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
            str = new String(result, "UTF-8");
        }

    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return str;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
    // do something with the string returned earlier
    Toast.makeText(ma.getApplicationContext(), "Calling validateUser with " + output, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ma.validateUser(output);
}
```

}

Here is the PHP script

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","S831987","831987",'D831987");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM USERS where 
EMAIL='$email' and PASSWORD ='$password'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];
if($data){
echo $data;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

here is the code which executes from the main activity when the login button is pressed by the user:

```
public void btnLoginClicked(View v){
    TextView em = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLogEmail);
    TextView pw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLogPassword);
    String email = em.getText().toString();
    String password = pw.getText().toString();
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    AsyncHttpPost async = new AsyncHttpPost(this, nameValuePair);
    async.execute("http://lamp.ms.wits.ac.za/~831987/isValidLogin.php");
}
```

Could anyone work out why I am receiving a blank response?
I tested the sql query as it is, with the correct variables and it works correctly.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","S831987","831987",'D831987");` is wrong, on the fourth (last) value, you are using ' to open, and " to close. Do `$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","S831987","831987","D831987");` - _also_ Most editors have color coding, you can use this feature to spot mistakes like this.

Comment: Thank you @Epodax, Unfortunately though, the returned value is still blank. :/

Comment: Could you try and check whether you receive the post value? `if(isset($_POST['email)){ print_r($_POST); }` (this is just an' example of how you can check)

Comment: @Epodax I added that line into my php script but nothing has changed.

Comment: It doesn't display anything? Do you see the php page / end up on it or?

Comment: @Epodax I'm actually not sure where the print_r would print the value so i could check it out :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78393/discussion-between-marko-vidalis-and-epodax).

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a ServiceHandler with a json object? This is how it works for me:

```
private class AsyncHttpPost extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "checking email and password...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg) {
        String mEmail = arg[0]; // email entered by user
        String mPassword = arg[1] // password entered by user

        // Preparing post params
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", mEmail));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));

        ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(YOUR_URL, ServiceHandler.POST, params);

        Log.d("SERVER Request: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                boolean error = jsonObj.getBoolean("error");
                // checking for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // username and password checked successfully
                } else {
                    Log.e("Server Error: ", "> " + jsonObj.getString("message"));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "JSON data error!");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Credits:

- http://www.go4expert.com/articles/step-step-guide-sending-data-android-t30182/
- http://www.onlymobilepro.com/2013/03/16/submitting-android-form-data-via-post-method/